# Emptying an Entry does not reset bound property

Tags: c#, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms application. It is using freshmvvm framework, which is not relevant for my issue. A page has a couple of Entries:

```
        <Entry Placeholder="Width" Text="{Binding TileWidth, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Entry Placeholder="Height" Text="{Binding TileHeight, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

These entries are bound to the ViewModel properties:

```
    int _tileWidth;
    public int TileWidth
    {
        get => _tileWidth;
        set
        {
            _tileWidth = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(TileWidth));
        }
    }

    int _tileHeight;
    public int TileHeight
    {
        get => _tileHeight;
        set
        {
            _tileHeight = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(TileHeight));
        }
    }
```

If the user enters some numbers into the entries, binding sets the properties accordingly. But if after that the user DELETES a value from an entry, binding does not reset the corresponding property to 0, which causes various issues. The execution doesn't even come to the property's set part. (If the user explicitly enters 0, the bound property is set to 0 as expected).

What am I missing?

Comment: `Entry.Text` is a `string` while you are binding to `int`, maybe that is the problem. Try to use a converter or `int?`.

Comment: @EvZ int? breaks the validation, but using string as the property type works. Please make you suggestion an answer, and I will mark it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Entry.Text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.entry.text?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Entry_Text) expects a `string` while you are binding it to `int`.
 In order to solve the problem you may:

1. Use an [`IValueConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) if you want to keep bindings to `int` properties (TileWidth, TileHeight).
2. Simply bind it to `string` properties. Not a good idea since we are talking about properties representing a `Width` & `Height`.

Comment: Thank you, using string as the property type fixes the issue. May I ask why I would need a converter?

Comment: If you want to keep the binding to `int` properties (TileWidth, TileHeight) `IValueConverter` will be needed to parse `string` to `int`. Please up vote my answer if you find it useful.

Comment: I understand, I am just not sure if I want it. I just don't know whether it is better to just get it as string and convert it to an int when I need it to  do the calculation with it, or to use the converter...

Comment: I don't think there is a doubt here - `Width` & `Height` should not be kept as a `string` and should represent the actual value in a correct numeric format.